# React button binding Interface modification

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a button that adds counters. It works but its a matter of UI structuring. When I click Add a counter, adds individual counters.

What I need is to have the independent counters, perhaps by programmatically the same result instead of onClick the button, having the +/- like `<button> {counter} </button>` directly.

What I have:

[image: what I have]

What I need (without clicking the above button):

[image: what I need]

When I click + or - then

```
TypeError: this.props.onIncrement is not a function
onClick

src/js/components/Posts.js:33
  30 | <div>
  31 |     <span>{this.props.value}</span>
  32 |     <button
> 33 |     onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement()}>
     | ^  34 |     +
  35 |     </button>
```

Code:

Counter.js

// ./src/js/components/Counter.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Counter extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <span>{this.props.value}</span>
            <button
            onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement()}>
            +
            </button>
            <button
            onClick={() => this.props.onDecrement()}>
            -
            </button>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Counter;
```

Action

// ./src/js/actions/counters.js

```
export const increment = (id) => {
    return {
    type: "INCREMENT",
    id
    };
};
export const decrement = (id) => {
    return {
        type: "DECREMENT",
        id
    };
};
export const add_counter = () => {
    return {
        type: "ADD_COUNTER"
    };
};
```

AddButton.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { add_counter } from '../actions/counters';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const AddButton = ({dispatch}) => (
  <button
  onClick={() => {
    dispatch(add_counter());
  }}>
    Add a counter
  </button>
);
export default connect()(AddButton);
```

counterlist.js

// ./src/js/components/CounterList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { increment, decrement } from '../actions/counters';
import Counter from './Counter';
const CounterList = ({
  counters,
  onIncrement,
  onDecrement
}) => (
  <ul>
    {counters.map(counter => 
      <Counter
        key={counter.id}
        value={counter.count}
        onIncrement={() => onIncrement(counter.id)}
        onDecrement={() => onDecrement(counter.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
);
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    counters: state
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onIncrement: (id) => dispatch(increment(id)),
    onDecrement: (id) => dispatch(decrement(id))
  };
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CounterList);
```

Posts.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from '../../logo.svg';
import '../../App.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Counter from './Counter'
import AddButton from './AddButton';

class Posts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            response: ''
        };
    }

    render() {

        return (
        <div className="App">
            {Array.isArray(this.state.response) &&
                this.state.response.map(resIndex => <div>
                    <AddButton/>
                    <Counter/>
                    {onIncrement(counter.id)}>
                    <h5> { resIndex.title } </h5>
                    <h5> { resIndex.body } </h5>
            </div>
            )}
        </div>
        )
    }
}


export default connect()(Posts);
```

Comment: Not sure I follow...so, instead of a single "Add" button, you want a "+" and "-" button that will increment/decrement your counter?

Comment: Yes. They show up only when I click add button, but I want them directly as if I already clicked

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I want them directly as if already clicked". If you want to programatically call them, why not just call `onIncrement(counter.id)` somewhere?

Comment: @technogeek1995 I get ./src/js/components/Posts.js
  Line 35:38:  'onIncrement' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 35:50:  'counter' is not defined      no-undef

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro Exactly, rendering directly the + and -.

Comment: Edit the question to add ` ./src/js/components/Posts.js` and the parent component for `Posts`. I can't tell what's wrong without seeing both of those components.

Comment: @technogeek1995 I just did.

Comment: I would recommend reading [this document](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) about lifting up state. What you need to do is move the state up out of counter and into your Post component so you can call functions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want with Redux given what you have above, but you won't have access to your `counter_id` inside your `Posts` component to increment/decrement a given counter. You would need to somehow get that information into your `Posts` component, which is where you wanted to call  increment/decrement programatically. This project would need restructured to resolve that issue. I would ditch Redux as it appears you're learning and I would focus on mastering state and props within React without Redux first.

This is how you would do it with Redux if you had access to a counter's ID. You'll pass into your component the increment/decrement functions as props by using the `mapDispatchToProps` function. You didn't have that in your `Posts` component which is why it was telling you your function was not defined. You have to have `mapDispatchToProps` for it to define the function on `this.props`.

I wasn't sure what you're doing to need to call `this.props.onIncrement`, so I just put it in `componentDidMount` for demonstration purposes.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Counter from './Counter';
import { increment, decrement } from '../actions/counters';
import AddButton from './AddButton';

class Posts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            response: ''
        };
    }

   componentDidMount() {
       this.props.onIncrement(<your_counter_id>);
   }

    render() {

        return (
        <div className="App">
            {Array.isArray(this.state.response) &&
                this.state.response.map(resIndex => <div>
                    <AddButton/>
                    <Counter/>
                    <h5> { resIndex.title } </h5>
                    <h5> { resIndex.body } </h5>
            </div>
            )}
        </div>
        )
    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  ({
    onIncrement: (id) => dispatch(increment(id)),
    onDecrement: (id) => dispatch(decrement(id))
  });
};

export default connect({}, mapDispatchToProps)(Posts);
```

Comment: Line 40:3:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
( on  ({
    onIncrement: (id) => etc. )..

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will accept it when I get it to work. I am learning so it means it needs restructuring or I won't learn

Comment: Do you want to see how to do it without redux? It's quite a lot simpler.

Comment: It needs to be with Redux. I was able to do it without Redux already

Comment: It needed only some restructuring. The only thing is the +/- counter is only showing first in the root className